# HomeBrew error message OSX

Tags: macos, permissions, homebrew

I have installed the latest Brew on OSX. On running update or installing new formulas I get the following error:

Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:

```
/usr/local/share/man/man5
```

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man5
```

And make sure that your user has write permission.

```
chmod u+w /usr/local/share/man/man5
```

At the moment I cannot find any information on what this means in context to `brew`. My goal is to understand it and not just do the permission change without understanding the implications or why that directory doesn't have the right permission.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

No one can give you a definite answer about the cause according only the info given from the description.

The most likely reason is that you used `sudo` with command `brew`, and the owner of some folder under `/usr/local` was changed to `root`.

Fix permission recursively,

```
sudo chown "$(whoami)":admin /usr/local/*
```

**Note**: Homebrew doesn't require `root` permission, never use `sudo` with command `brew`.

BTW, maybe `brew doctor` will provide more info about this problem.

Comment: `brew doctor` was the best advice!